# Why are *arg and **kwarg needed when we can store a list in an argument?

Tags: python, class

I have 2 versions of code to initialize a class object:

Version without *args:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, courses):
        self.name = name
        self.courses = courses

Peter = Student('Peter', ['Math', 'English'])
```

Version with *args:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, *courses):
        self.name = name
        self.courses = courses

Peter = Student('Peter', 'Math', 'English')
```

It seems like both of them work. Are both versions acceptable and practical? Are there any situations when *args must be used while storing lists/tuples/dictionaries into arguments will give errors?

Comment: Would say both are acceptable, but in the second case (i.e. using *args) order counts.  Meaning the first case could be changed to `def __init__(self, courses, name)` but this wouldn't work for the 2nd case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you ever *need* to use the starred form, but there are certainly cases where it is *convenient*.

This is largely a philosophical question. Is it one argument, which happens to be a list, or is it multiple arguments? The answer is not always obvious. One thing you need to consider is how the function will be used. In this case, I suspect that using the "starred" version will force you to use a lot of stars at the call sites as well. For example, if you have read the data for a student from a database, you are likely to have the courses in a list, so doing

```
s = Student(name, courses)
```

looks a bit cleaner than

```
s = Student(name, *courses)
```

However, if you are going to initialize all your student objects explicitly in the program (probably unlikely in the case of students, but imagine some other set of objects which is fixed when the program is written), the multiple-argument version might be cleaner. For example,

```
apollo_11 = Crew('Armstrong', 'Aldrin', 'Collins')
```

might be cleaner than

```
apollo_11 = Crew(['Armstrong', 'Aldrin', 'Collins'])
```

(assuming that we treat all crew members as equal and don't bother with who was commanding or piloting what). (*Edit: This is also a poor example because there were always three of them.)*

It is worth noticing that you can only have one "starred" parameter (and, as was pointed out in comments, it has to go last). If you want to keep track of both courses and extracurricular activities, it will have to be

```
peter = Student('Peter', ['Math', 'English'], ['Chess', 'Archery'])
```